# Laravel back using {{ URL::previous() }} doesn't work if there are validation errors

Tags: laravel

I want to make a cancel button on a simple CRUD edit form. However it seems that when there are validation errors the cancel button does not work.

I guess because it routes from controller@edit to controller@update the button just goes to controller@edit again instead of the actual previous page. Is this normal or did I do something wrong? How do I make it work?

**attendee/edit.blade.php**

```
<div class=pull-right>
{{Form::submit('Update',array('class'=>'btn btn-success'))}}
<a href = "{{URL::previous()}}" class = 'btn btn-warning'>Cancel</a>
</div>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('user/attendees', 'UserController@getAttendees');
Route::resource('attendee', 'AttendeeController');
```

**attendee controller**

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    if(empty($user->id))
        return Redirect::to('/');

    //return if attendee doesn't belong to user
    if( !($user->attendee->contains($id)) )
        return Redirect::to('user/index')->with( 'error', 'attendee id error.' );

    $attendee = Attendee::find($id);
    return View::make('attendees.edit', compact('attendee'));
}

/**
 * Update the specified attendee in storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function update($id)
{
    $attendee = Attendee::findOrFail($id);

    $validator = Validator::make($data = Input::all(), Attendee::$rules);

    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput()->with('id', $id);
    }

    $attendee->update($data);

    return Redirect::intended();
}
```

**user controller**

```
public function getAttendees()
{
    list($user,$redirect) = $this->user->checkAuthAndRedirect('user');
    if($redirect){return $redirect;}

    // Show the page
    return View::make('site/user/attendees/index', compact('user'));
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the code? Chances are, you're using a submit button.

Answer (score 3):

It's actually working correctly, it's just the usage that is incorrect.

Take the following:

1. You submit a form at `GET /attendee/edit/{id}`
2. The form takes you to `POST /attendee/edit/{id}`
3. You fail validation and are redirected to `GET /attendee/edit/{id}`

You cannot link to a page using a method other than `GET`. Your previous route was actually `POST /attendee/edit/{id}` but the link will always be `GET`.

Instead, nominate a page to be redirected to, I usually use the index for the section.

Comment: I suspected that was what was happening but you stated it much better than I could. I can't nominate a page though because the edit page is shared. Is there a way to get the last GET so I can go back that way? It seems to me that URL::previous should use the last GET :`(

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it just returns `Request::server('HTTP_REFERER')` which will always be the previous page. There are a couple of ways, but they all get more and more complicated. Surely `URL::to('/user/attendees')` would suffice?

Comment: I will run into problems when the admin tries to edit the attendee :( The back button on the browser works fine. I guess I will just take out the cancel button and let them use that...

Comment: There should really be separate pages for admins and normal users.

Comment: I don't see how that makes sense for every CRUD model since the forms in the views are exactly the same other than the back button...I guess I could use blade template to overwrite the button between the user and the admin but that feels wrong somehow.

Comment: @ollieread no, only in the most basic CRUD system with no flexibility. It is good UI design to let the users navigate with the least amount of clicks. That means adding links to the same actions in several places in the app. The back should always go 'back'. The function of 'back' is not a technical one, it's the user that knows what page he/she came from. A reload or validation should not result in the previous page being overwritten (unless explicitly asked for), since logically you are still on the same page.I believe this to be laravel's misconception, and it should solve it. Use session..

Comment: @MichielvanderBlonk It's not Laravels misconception, it's the way that things have always worked. You click submit, you are sent to a new request, the previous page doesn't exist anymore. It should not always go back at all, if you go from GET to POST to GET and want to go back, you're going to hit a POST, which just won't work, you cannot link to a POST request and nor would you want to. 

What you're saying, goes against how HTTP works, and how it has always worked, if you submit a form you are going to a new page, that would constitute an explicit request.

Comment: You can always store the last tangible URL in a session, but mostly that's messy and will create horrid UI, especially if the user has gone straight to this page, now they're stuck. Going back or "cancelling" a form should take you back to the show or index, whatever the previous page would be the application workflow, there is already a back button in the browser if they specifically want to go back to the previous request.

Comment: @ollieread from an application point of view, cancel should work exactly like the back button. Considering direct access as an example, I believe the cancel button could either redirect back to the index/show, ask the user what they want, or use HTTP_REFERRER (although that's not reliable). The Cancel button is close enough to the Submit button for people to automatically click it once they are busy. They expect a certain flow. What the OP is experiencing is that the Cancel button does nothing (at least not visibly) and that's always wrong, whether technically and theoretically right or not.

Comment: @MichielvanderBlonk OP is experiencing that issue because he has a cancel button that works like the back button.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should add a hidden input, like this

```
{!! Form::hidden('redirect_to', old('redirect_to', URL::previous())) !!}
```

and use this value in your link:

```
<a href="{{ old('redirect_to', URL::previous())}}">cancel</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

`Redirect::back()` doesn't really accomplish the right thing when using the validator provided by Laravel. What I've done before is pass the page to redirect back to as a hidden input in the form, and simply ignore it using `Input::except("return")`. Here's what I mean:

```
// On your HTML Form
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="{{ Request::path() }}" />

// In your PHP Controller
$validator = Validator::make($data = Input::except("return"), Attendee::$rules);
if ($validator->fails())
{
    return Redirect::to(Input::get("return"))->withErrors($validator)->withInput()->with('id', $id);
}
```

Hope that can help shed some light. Other options are returning to a higher up, such as instead of `attendee/edit/{id}` redirect to `attendee/edit/`, but it all depends on the structure of you website.

Comment: That is interesting...so send the Request::path to the controller and then return the value and use JQuery to change the button a href?

Comment: `Request::path()` will return a string representation of the current path, so in this case on stack overflow: `questions/27707325/laraval-back-using...`. I'm not sure about the button you're talking about, as the redirect is handled server-side, and using JQuery is setting the button on the client-side.

Comment: Ah I see. I want to change the cancel button, not the redirect after validation. I found a simple solution using jquery :D

Comment: Yeah, must have misunderstood your question. Glad you got it working though!

Comment: There seems to be a bug with Chrome catching each POST in the history, so I might be using this after all.

Answer (score 1):

I am now using the browser back via JS in *onclick*. Seems to work:

```
<a onclick="window.history.back();">Back</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this jquery for the cancel button.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.back').click(function(){
        parent.history.back();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

May you use the Front-End validation to test the input validation without a need to reload the page. So the {{URL::previous()}} won't affected.
The simple way to do that is by using Ajax or validator.js in your Laravel cade.

Here is a full example how to use jquery ajax in Laravel 5 to test the validation, may help:
http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-5-ajax-request-validation-exampleexample.html